# Conditional Rendering on Click Button using State Variable in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make responsive menu bar where the menu needs to be displayed and hidden. It is not working as expected. So, I did the simple demo version to check if it works, but it does not work as well. Please let me know why it is not working.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  console.log("Show value: ", show);

  const menuToggle = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={menuToggle}>
          Show
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={menuToggle}>
          Hide
        </button>
      </div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And styles.css is as follows:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  opacity: ${({ show }) => (show ? 1 : 0)}; 
}
```

However, when I set opacity directly as 1 or 0, then it works. It makes me think that the CSS property is not set on component re-rendering. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Edit:
In my actual project, I need to use styled component and have it under @media screen. Part of my code is:

```
<NavMenu>
    {data.map((elementList, index) => (
        <NavItem key={index}>
            <NavLinks to={elementList.to}>{elementList.text}</NavLinks>              
        </NavItem>
    ))}
</NavMenu>
```

and the component NavMenu is defined as:

```
export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;


  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: ${({ show }) => (show ? 1 : 0)};
    visibility: ${({ show }) => (show ? "visible" : "hidden")};
    transform: translateY(${({ show }) => (show ? "0" : "-100vh")});
    transition: transform 5s ease;
    background-color: #071c2f;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get confused with what you mean by *it is not working as expected*, do you want to always show the menu bar in large screen and controls it in smaller screen?. About using media queries in react JS, I personally suggest you to use a CSS framework that supports media queries and handle the state the react way.

If you insist to do media queries with react JS, this is what I come up with.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  //control the visibility of the navbar
  const [navOpen, setNavOpen] = useState(true);
  //default value as the user open the web page
  const [match, setMatch] = useState(
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)").matches
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    //update the current match
    const handler = (e) => setMatch(e.matches);
    //add the listener to watch current view size (media query) and change state as soon as it matches
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)").addEventListener("change", handler);
    //clean up useEffect
    return () => {
      window
        .matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)")
        .removeEventListener("change", handler);
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <NavMenu match={match} isOpen={navOpen}>
        <ul>1</ul>
        <ul>2</ul>
        <ul>3</ul>
        <ul>4</ul>
        <ul>5</ul>
      </NavMenu>
      <NavTrigger match={match} setNavOpen={setNavOpen} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

the code above is the parent component. The component watch for the screen changes that happens in user's web browsers.

```
const NavTrigger = ({ match, setNavOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* if the current view size is less than 960px show the button */}
      {/* visibility through dom manipulation */}
      {match && (
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setNavOpen(true)}>
            Show
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setNavOpen(false)}>
            Hide
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {/* implementation with inline style to set opcaity */}
      <h1 style={{ opacity: match ? 1 : 0 }}>
        This &lsquo;Hello World&rsquo; only shows on mobile (960px screen size)
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

as for the trigger, the component controls the state of the navbar visibility on screen below 960px.

```
const NavMenu = ({ children, match, isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <nav
      style={{
        border: "1px solid red",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        padding: "0 2rem",
        opacity: !match || isOpen ? 1 : 0,
        visibility: !match || isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden",
        transform: !match || isOpen ? "translateX(0)" : "translateX(-100vh)",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

the nav accept two state, one is from mediaqueries and one is current open state. So even if the open state is `false`, in large screen (above 960px) the navbar will always be visible.

You can later stylize the navbar component with class or inline style. It should not affect the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the conditional styling directly in your `JSX`.

```
<h1 style={{ opacity: show ? 1 : 0 }}>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: I need to use it as a component and use @media screen. Something like this:``` opacity: ${({ show }) => (show ? 1 : 0)};
    visibility: ${({ show }) => (show ? "visible" : "hidden")};
    transform: translateY(${({ show }) => (show ? "0" : "-100vh")}); ```

Answer (score 0):

You can render conditionally the whole class of css, I think that's the best approach and no matter the number of classes you can render them conditionally.

Example:

```
<h1 className={`${show ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: Then why is the demo code not working? I have also edited my question mentioning my actual project. I need to use styled component and media query. Using className or inline style is not helpful for me.

Comment: I don't see a problem, separate everything except what you want to render conditionally in one css class and give that class to NavMenu, other properties which you want to render conditionally keep in second class which you will render as shown above.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working. I am completely lost. Whatever initial value I set for "show", only that action takes place for all opacity, visibility and transform. I can see the show value getting changed, by doing console.log, but these properties have no effect on the re-rendering.

Comment: if you can copy paste your code here https://codesandbox.io/ i could take a closer look

Comment: Thank you evryone for trying to help me. I fixed it. I missed a code on <NavMenu>, which should be: <NavMenu show={show}>. I have marked @Dharma's answer as acceptable as he provided the clue on "nav accepts two state".. Thank you ajdin for offering your generous help. Much appreciate.